# Access a button with its name in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

These are the html for a button which changes x-path dynamically but "Show Actions" remains the same. I am confused whether "Show Actions" is name, title or id of the button.

Is there anyway to click this button with "Show Actions" or any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Show Actions` seems to be the **text** content of the element.
You can try clicking it with the following way:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Show Actions')]").click()
```

Or

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(.,'Show Actions')]").click()
```

You will possibly need to add an expected condition to wait for this element clickability, as following:

```py
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(.,'Show Actions')]"))).click()
```